# Making dragging register as clicking in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: html, click, drag

I'm trying to create a canvas sort of thing in HTML without using the Canvas element. It's working so far, but one thing I can't figure out how to do is make dragging register as clicking.
For example, if the user click on element A, it registers as a click on element A, obviously.
If I drag across A and B, though, I want it to register as a click on both A and B instead of highlight A and B.
By drag, I mean press down with mouse/trackpad, hold, and move it across A and B, then releasing. It's different from drag-and-drop; it's more like drawing on a canvas element. This can use
For context, all elements are characters inside span elements.

I don't know what to try; when I don't do anything (i.e. leave it as characters in span elements), dragging ends up highlighting, not clicking.
Thanks!